# Перестала работать эмулятор в Android studio

Tags: android-studio

С утра эмулятор запускался без проблем, но сейчас вообще перестал работать и выдаёт такую ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текстовый вариант:

Intel HAXM is required to run this AVD.
Your CPU does not support required features (VT-x or SVM).

Unfortunately, your computer does not support hardware accelerated virtualization.
Here are some of your options:
 1) Use a physical device for testing
 2) Develop on a Windows/OSX computer with an Intel processor that supports VT-x and NX
 3) Develop on a Linux computer that supports VT-x or SVM
 4) Use an Android Virtual Device based on an ARM system image
   (This is 10x slower than hardware accelerated virtualization)

У меня стоит процессор Amd Ryzen 7.
Читал что для решения этой проблемы надо включить виртуализацию, но она у меня включена; Ещё что надо установить Intel HAXM, при установке вылезает ошибка:
Unable to install Intel HAXM
Your CPU does not support required features (VT-x or SVM).
Unfortunately, your computer does not support hardware accelerated virtualization.
Here are some of your options:
 1) Use a physical device for testing
 2) Develop on a Windows/OSX computer with an Intel processor that supports VT-x and NX
 3) Develop on a Linux computer that supports VT-x or SVM
 4) Use an Android Virtual Device based on an ARM system image
   (This is 10x slower than hardware accelerated virtualization)

При запуске эмулятора CPU/ABI arm64-v8a, эмулятор пытается запустить android, но ничего дальше экрана загрузки не уходит.
Что делать для исправления данной ошибки? Т.к. буквально с утра всё работало

Comment: intel HAXM - технология для процессоров Intel. для AMD этот драйвер не нужно устанавливать. Для современных процессоров AMD эмулятор использует технологию hyper-v  или программную эмуляцию через arm-образы устройств

Answer (score 2):

Проблема была в том что Windows 10 загрузила какие-то обновления, после их удаления всё заработало нормально